# Perl EPIC in eclipse: How do I get rid of this Ant Build dialog when trying to run a Perl script?

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, ant, epic

I have installed Perl EPIC in eclipse Oxygen. Every time I try to Run or Debug a Perl script it keeps throwing up this annoying dialog:

[image: Debug As...]

I have previously been able debug/run Perl scripts straight from eclipse before without this, even stepping through each line to see inspect Variables. I have already checked "**Ant Build**" under "**Filter checked launch configuration types:**" in **Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch Config**, but it seems to make no difference.

EDIT: this seems to be specific to certain Perl script files. I can run/debug some Perl script with no problem, but others keep triggering this dialog. All Perl scripts have the same file extension (.pl), they are all in the same folder and are all created within the same eclipse EPIC project...so this is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: Is this under linux or windows?

Comment: Windows 7, Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), EPIC 0.7.5

Comment: I tried to install Eclipse 2020.06 on a Windows 10 virtual machine, but the installation was extremely slow and slowed down the whole system, such that any other app running did not respond. After installation, I tried to launch it, but the same problem and I gave up. I can recommend VS Code, it installs quickly and works very well (so far) on Windows 10 for writing Perl code.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks, I will take a look at VS Code...but my machine is a beast - no issues with performance (only the occasional bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround by adding another Run Configuration as follows:

Run -> Run Configurations... -> Perl Local -> [+New]:

Name: `<Name_of_this_run/launch_configuration>`
Project: `<Name_of_Perl_Project>`
File to execute: `<name_of_perlscript.pl>`

The relates to another question I have about whether a Run Configuration can be applied to multiple files based on a file name pattern.